# Show that $\int (f'(x))^2dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}Var(Y)$

Tags: probability, integration, proof-writing, normal-distribution, variance

> Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\int
>  (f'(x))^2dx=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}Var(Y)$$ where $Y$ is a Normal random variable with $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=\frac{1}{2}$

I know that $f(x)$ is the standard normal density,
$$f'(x)=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})$$
and
$$f'(x)^2=\frac{x^2}{2\pi}\exp(-x^2)$$
then
$$\int
 (f'(x))^2dx=\int \frac{x^2}{2\pi}\exp(-x^2)dx$$

but I don't know what to do from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
\int_0^\infty u^s\exp(-u)\:du=\Gamma(s+1),\quad s>-1. \tag1
$$ Then, by the change of variable $x=\sqrt{u}$, $u:=x^2$, $dx=\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{u}}$ in the following integrand
$$
\int_0^\infty x^2\exp(-x^2)\:dx
$$ one gets 
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty (f'(x))^2dx&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\infty x^2\exp(-x^2)\:dx
\\\\&=\frac1{4\pi}\int_0^\infty u^{1/2}\exp(-u)\:du
\\\\&=\frac1{4\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac32\right)
\\\\&=\frac1{8\sqrt{\pi}}.
\end{align}
$$